# Why is ant design pro not using config.dev.ts despite correctly passing in UMI_ENV=dev

Tags: typescript, antd, ant-design-pro, umijs

Currently, I have a folder structure that looks like this

```
.
└── config/
    ├── config.dev.ts
    ├── config.local.ts
    ├── config.ts
    └── defaultSettings.ts
```

My `Package.json` commands look like this:

```
"ant:start:localapi": "cross-env REACT_APP_ENV=local UMI_ENV=local HTTPS=true MOCK=none umi dev"

"ant:start:devapi": "cross-env REACT_APP_ENV=dev UMI_ENV=dev HTTPS=true MOCK=none umi dev"
```

Here is my dev configuration file:

```
// https://umijs.org/config/
import { defineConfig } from 'umi';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    // https://github.com/zthxxx/react-dev-inspector
    'react-dev-inspector/plugins/umi/react-inspector',
  ],
  // https://github.com/zthxxx/react-dev-inspector#inspector-loader-props
  inspectorConfig: {
    exclude: [],
    babelPlugins: [],
    babelOptions: {},
  },
  define: {
    'process.env.UMI_ENV': process.env.UMI_ENV,
    ...
  },
});
```

When I run `ant:start:devapi`, Umijs ends up using the `config.local.ts` file despite correctly passing in the `UMI_ENV` env variable.

I understand that there is prioritization that happens where local is to be used if `UMI_ENV` is not present, however, I have confirmed that `UMI_ENV` is passed correctly as `dev`.

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Umi.js config profile priority:

The higher up, the more specific and higher the priority, and high-quality ones can be moved down.

```
config.ts

config.${UMI_ENV}.ts

config.${dev | prod}.ts

config.${dev | prod}.${UMI_ENV}.ts

config.local.ts
```

I try below way to solve this problem:

```json
{
  "script": {
    "build": "cross-env UMI_ENV=prod max build",
    "build:test": "cross-env UMI_ENV=test max build",
  }
}
```

Create files: `/config/config.prod.prod.ts` and `/config/config.prod.test.ts` .

More discussion: https://github.com/umijs/umi/discussions/8341